# the location of the textView in the viewController when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I have two pages in the storyboard (let's call VC1 and VC2). in one I have a table with cells, and in the second I output a label and textView. depending on the number of the cell I have different text and different number of cells in VC2. I pre-made VC2 with four Labels and TexView, but when I need to output two textViews I just hide using the isHidden method and I have an empty space when I flip. How can I solve the problem? maybe I can do everything via textView.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? And as far as i understood the problem is that too many text views and all labels are being hidden, but only 2 of 4 textviews and none of the labels should be hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you could change the textView's frame.height variable.
Instead of only hiding the textView, like you are doing now:

```
yourTextView.isHidden = true
```

Also add the line editing the frame height:

```
yourTextView.isHidden = true
yourTextView.frame.height = 0
```

But make sure to change it back after re-showing it.

Comment: True yourTextView.frame.size.height = 0